# What's default for LSMinimumSystemVersion?

Tags: macos, launch-services

macOS applications can specify minimum required operating system version by including [`LSMinimumSystemVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-113253) key in its `Info.plist` file. What is supposed to happen if this key is not present?

Answer (score 0):

If `LSMinimumSystemVersion` isn't present, there's simply no check if the app supports the current macOS version before attempting to launch it. It's launched regardless of the macOS version.